# I have to restart GeoServer when I change the mapping file?

Tags: geoserver, wfs, geoserver-app-schema

I'm trying to use `GeoServer` with app-schema plug-in to map a complex features. I have some trouble but my question is: I have to restart `GeoServer` every time that I modify the mapping file so that the `wfs` request work properly?

Comment: I don't know, but did you try just hitting "reload" in the status panel?

Comment: The app-schema plug-in don't work with `GeoServer` user interface. I only make wfs request via browser as shown here [link](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/app-schema/tutorial.html) at the end.

Comment: The app-schema plugin has now some support for the user interface. Did you try reloading, or not?